# Angular: how to listen for response that you yourself don't make?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-http

In Angular, is there a way to listen for a response to a request that you yourself don't make?  Specifically I'm implementing file upload to Node.js, and I'm submitting the form programmatically:

HTML:

```
<form enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
      action    =  "/blah/fileupload"
      method    =  "post"
          id    =  "upload_file"
>
  <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onFileSelect(event)" name="bulk_uploads" />
</form>
```

Angular controller:

```
  $scope.onFileSelect = function(event)
  {
    var form_elem = document.getElementById('upload_file');    
    form_elem.submit();
  }
```

The issue is submitting the form in this fashion does not return a promise, and if I submit the form like so:

```
$http.post('/blah/fileupload', { files : event.target.files })
```

then there is no way to get to the uploaded files once it hits the Node server (e.g. req.files is empty).

Is there a way to listen for the server's response to 'blah/fileupload' by submitting the form programatically as I'm currently doing, or am I going about this the wrong way?

NOTE: I'm hoping to not use the [Interceptors API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) for the sake of performance.  If there's not a major performance hit, then please do let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not an answer to my specific 'how do I create an Angular-side service endpoint?' question, I was able to solve the problem I was having by reading the file contents in the client before posting that data to the server:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('upload_file');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', onFileSelect);

function onFileSelect(event)
{
  var fileList = event.target.files;
  for (var i = 0, totalFiles = fileList.length; i < totalFiles; ++i)
  {
    var file = fileList.item(i);
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.addEventListener('load', onFileLoad); 
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
}

var fileData = new Array();
function onFileLoad(event)
{
  fileData.push(event.target.result);

  if (fileData.length == totalFiles)
  {
    sendFilesToServer(fileData);
  }
}


function sendFilesToServer(fileData)
{
  $http.post('/blah/fileupload', { files : fileData })
       .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
         {
          // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main advice: 
1) use some external angular file upload library, for example [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)
2) subscribe to `submit` event from the controller:

```
document.getElementById('upload_file').addEventListener('submit', your_handler)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Good suggestion re. ng-file-upload.  Unfortunately listening for the 'submit' event won't do exactly what I need - it will fire when the front end submits the form, rather than when the back end sends it's response.